# Why I am not able to direct user to my blog section without login?

Tags: redirect, login, user-registration

```
function wpse_41699_wp(){
    if( is_page('Login')||is_page('register')||is_page('Blog')||is_page('blog') ){
        return;
    }else{
        if(!is_user_logged_in()){
            $url = get_bloginfo('home').'/login';//ACW-login location need to be specified
            header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden');
            header("Location: $url");
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

In the function.php, I added above code,
I used above code to disable user access to my site without login, but I want to make regular use able to access blog section which is a page named Blog. but I do not konw why still, I will be direct to login page, while register page is been successufully unblocked from been request to login.

Can anyone help me on this one?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your blog page designated as the posts page under Settings > Reading?

Comment: yes, I did. that is the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you designate a page as the posts page, `is_page()` will no longer be true for that page, as it is now the "Home Page". Use [`is_home()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home) instead to test if the posts page is the current page.

Comment: It seems counter-intuitive, but when you set a static front page and posts page, what you'd think as your "home page" is the *front page* and can be tested via `is_front_page()`. only when you haven't set those options will your *front page* be both the home page *and* front page.